# How can I plot a figure with the same style y_axis like this?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'd like to plot a figure where the y_axis with scientific notation. But the default style of `matplotlib.pyplot` is ugly, so how can I get a figure like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

If you want a different style with scientific notation, you can use LaTeX to render all your labels in your plot.

Please check this resource: https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html